# How to find the MAX in any given list of numbers?

Tags: list, scheme

Is it possible to find the highest number in a list given any arbitrary number of items in the list? If so, please let me know how it can be done. I'm fairly new to Scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [max](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._max%29%29) function. Since your input is list of numbers, you can use [apply](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) function.

```
> (max 1 2 3 4)
4
> (apply max '(1 2 3 4 5 6 100 89 23))
100
>
```